# Defining the Polar set

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-cone

For a subset P of R^n (real numbers) the polar set is defined by:
$$
P^*:= \{ y\in \Bbb R^n\mid  y\cdot x \leq 1 \text{ for all } x\in P \}.
$$

Can someone break the definition into plain english as im struggling to understand the notations used and such a sets structure.

The best guess ive got is: $P*$ is defined as the set of all (x,y) which follows that, for all real y ($\in \mathbb {R^n})$ there exists an x in P that satisfies $y·x \le 1$

Even if have this correct how is this useful in general geometry? The original question is to show that if $P$ is a convex set that contains the origin then (P*)*=P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to read the definition literally is to say the following:

> $P^*$ is the set of all vectors $y$ for which $y \cdot x \leq 1$ holds for all $x \in P$.

For more information on how to make sense of definitions like these, see the wiki page for ["set-builder notation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). The idea behind a polar set is that it provides a "test" by which we can check whether or not an element fails to be in $P$.

To see how this works, let's consider an example. Take the set
$$
P = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid  0 \leq x_2 \leq x_1\}.
$$
That is, $P$ is the region in the $xy$-plane satisfying $0 \leq y \leq x$.  As it turns out, the polar set will be equal to
$$
P^* = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x_1 \leq 0 \text{ and } x_2 \leq -x_1\}.
$$
Now, consider the point $v = (1,2)$, which we can see fails to be an element of $P$.  The polar set gives us another way to show that $v$ fails to be an element of $P$: if there is an element $w \in P^*$ for which $w \cdot x > 1$, then we can be sure (by the definition of a polar cone) that $v$ is not an element of $P$.

In this case, it is useful to consider the element $w = (-2,2) \in P^*$.  We find that
$$
v \cdot w = 1 \cdot (-2) + 2 \cdot (2) = 2 > 1.
$$
If $v$ were an element of $P$, then by the definition of a polar cone, any $w \in P^*$ would have to satisfy $v \cdot w \leq 1$. Because that fails to happen here, we can be sure that $v$ is not an element of $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, i still have some issue with x and y and their definitions. As i read it, x and y have domains as subsets of P but how are they defined, ie from your example can x and y take any vectors within R^2 or are there restrictions within the set, or does any point need to satisfy x•y for everyother point in R^2 to be within P?

Comment: @SebastienBienfait The description of $x$ in the definition of $P$ does not carry over as a global statement about what "$x$" is supposed to represent. Regardless, I'll give the variables outside the set-definitions a new name in order to avoid confusion

Comment: @SebastienBienfait Do you have any experience programming?

Comment: Some with Python yes

Comment: @SebastienBienfait If that's so, in the definition $P = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid  0 \leq x_2 \leq x_1\}$, you can think of the part to the right of $\mid$, namely $0 \leq x_2 \leq x_1$, as describing a function we could call `isElement`. `isElement` accepts any argument $x \in \Bbb R^2$ (which is what is written to the left of the $\mid$), and `isElement(x)` returns true if $x \in P$ and false otherwise. Per the description, `isElement` returns the result of $0 \leq x_2 \leq x_1$. Note that $x$ is only defined for this subprogram, so there is no restriction to its use in the "main code"

Comment: That is, by writing this description, I have not stated that $x$ is necessarily an element of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Say $P$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ( perhaps convex) that contains $0$ (in its interior).
Consider a hyperplane is given by the equation in $x$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i = b$$

Assume now $b\ne 0$ (that is, the hyperplane does not containg $0$). Dividing by $b$ we get an equivalent equation
$$\sum a'_i x_i = 1$$
where $a'_i = \frac{a_i}{b}$.  So we can write the equation of a hyperplane that does not pass through the origin as
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 1$$
There is also an advantage in that now the equation is unique.

Now, we want all these hyperplanes (not containing $0$) that leave $P$ on ones side. Now, a hyperplane of equation $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} = 1$ divides the space into two halfspaces $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} \le (\ge) 1$. Since $P$ contains $0$, and $ \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{0}=0 < 1$, for $P$ to be on one side of the hyperplane is equivalent to
$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} \le 1$$
for all $x \in P$.

Now, assume that $P$ is closed, convex, containing $0$ and $z$ a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ not contained in $P$. Intuitively it should be clear ( and can be proved) that there exists a hyperplane separating strictly $P$ and $z$. In other words, there exist $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$y \cdot x < 1$$ for all $x \in P$ and
$$y \cdot z>1$$

A moment's thought shows that $y\in P^{\star}$, and $z \not \in (P^{\star})^{\star}$.  The conclusion is that $(P^{\star})^{\star}$ must be included in $P$. However, it is easy to see that $P$ is contained in $(P^{\star})^{\star}$. By double inclusion we get the equality $P=(P^{\star})^{\star}$.